# Какие наиболее востребованные направления для разработчика на java

Tags: java

Хочу начать учить java. Подскажите, что учить и направление.

Comment: Сначала core изучите. https://metanit.com/java/tutorial/

Comment: алгоритмы, структуры данных

Answer (score 1):

> *Сразу скажу, что это не волшебный и правильный путь. Я лишь опишу своё
>   видение того, какой путь должен быть пройден. Не претендую на истину в
>   последней инстанции. Я выражаю своё видение.*
>
> ***Буду рад, если в комментариях под моим ответом вы cкоррелируете моё
>   видение.***

Начинать с ключевых моментов о том что такое классы, методы, циклы. В общем очень плотно изучать весь `JavaCore` + `Алгоритмы` и `Структуры данных`. В одном ответе даже невозможно описать все темы. Изучение `Java`  `Core` это довольно долгий длительный процесс в котором как раз вы сможете определиться - хотите ли заниматься `Java`.

Это не реклама, но для `JavaCore` рекомендую для изучения `JavaRush`. Пройдя там курс, вы будете уверенно знать `Core`, так как проделаете много практических задач. Или же можно основные темы в курсе на `Stepik` - https://stepik.org/course/187/promo. В любом случае даже если вы начнете со `JavaRush` данный курс на `Stepik` тоже обязательно.

После `Core` надо изучать `Java EE` - Сервлеты и всё что с ними связано. Написать минимальный web-проект на `Java EE` + `JDBC`.

После `Java EE` надо начинать изучать `Hibernate`, `Spring Core` и все основные модули `Spring Data`, `Spring Security`, `Spring Security`, `Spring Boot`. А так же переделать web-проект, который делали ранее, на `Spring`.

Ко всему этому надо изучить основы `SQL`, `HTML+CSS`.

Это супер минимум тех знаний, которые нужны разработчику.

Удачи!

Comment: Не совсем согласен. Для начала, JavaRush предоставляет довольно мало полезной информации и, по сути, может привлечь только практическими задачами (многие из которых очень скучные, к слову), при этом сам курс уже старый, так как он учит Java 7. Насчет Java EE тоже не соглашусь, ему нет смысла учить Java EE, потому что в 90%+ используют Spring. Насчет сервлетов вполне нормальная идея, для ознакомления пойдет. Также советую автору понять принцип работы JDBC и Hibernate, это очень важно и об этом часто спрашивают на собеседованиях.

Comment: @NarasuOo Я согласен и JavaRush сам не проходил, но по знакомым ребятам, которые начали изучать JavaRush было неплохоим началом для того чтобы набить руки для решения задачи и понимания синтаксиса. По JavaEE мне кажется стоит пройтись и изучить хотя бы в общем, так как это поможет понять Spring. Иначе он будет казаться магией, не говоря о Spring Boot.

Comment: любое изучение языка я считаю надо обязательно сочетать с чтением книги, какие грамотные курсы не были бы (а таких очень мало на самом деле) в книге всегда больше углублений которые точно рано или поздно понадобятся.

Comment: @Njdos если хочешь пойти в андройд, то лучше изучай котлин, его и гугл признал официальным языком разработки под андройд, да и хайпа с ним сейчас много, он все больше теснит джаву в этой сфере