# Java development какие есть направление и востебиваємость их на ринке (желатель

Tags: java, база-данных, алгоритм, строки, сеть

Java development  какие есть направление и востебиваємость их на ринке (желательно описать) 
Спс

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие наиболее востребованные направления для разработчика на java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1121592/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java)

Answer (score 1):

посмотрите на схему.

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2019/10/the-java-developer-roadmap.html

думаю вам по этой схеме в плотную

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/473631)

Comment: Спасибо за замечание исправил